# C# lambda expressions, sub child query

Tags: c#, linq, lambda

I'm trying to query an object hierarchy which is like:

Customer --> `IList` of Orders
&
Order --> `IList` of Products

My `Customer` object has a collection of orders and my `Order` object has a collection of products.

What I am trying to do is to get the customers who ordered a particular product. I will query this by `product id`. At the end of the query I want to obtain a `Customer list`.

I tried this, but it didn't work.

```
public ICollection<Customer> GetByParticularProduct(int productId)
{

    return allCustomers
    .Where(customer => customer.Orders
.Any(order => order.Products
.Any(prod => prod.Id == productId)))
    .ToList();
}
```

How can I get through this?

Comment: What do you mean by "didn't work"? What's `ProductsAny()`?

Comment: Sorry, I revised it. I mean by didn't work. I get an ArgumentNullException and figured out that the problem was not my query. It was my mapping. My Orders collection was not mapped right and it was alwasy null. Now I mapped it right and it works. Thanks for your concern anyway...

Answer (score 0):

If your collections may contain `null`'s, you might try this

```
public ICollection<Customer> GetByParticularProduct(int productId)
{
    return (from cust in allCustomers.Where(x => x != null)
            let orders = cust.Orders.Where(x => x != null)
            let prods = orders.SelectMany(x => x.Products).Where(x => x != null)
            where prods.Any(x => x.Id == productId)
            select cust)
           .ToList();
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
return allCustomers
    .Where(customer => customer.Orders
        .Any(order => order.Products
            .Any(prod => prod.Id == productId))).ToList();
```

or

```
return allCustomers
    .Where(customer => customer.Orders
        .Any(order => order.ProductId == productId))).ToList();
```

Comment: Your first one looks identical to the sample provided by the OP